# How to split the number in js

Tags: javascript

I have only one number like "100000"

I wan't to  split this number same as [20000,20000,20000,20000,20000] in array

so if number is 138000 then it should be like [20000,20000,20000,20000,20000,20000,18000]

How to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking members to write codes for you. You have to explain what you have tried and finally ask why your code is not working.

Comment: Please add a basic snippet of what you have, and mention what you have tried.

Comment: actually I did not find any solution to try that's why I asked a question here..

Comment: I know you just want to get your code working, and there are multiple good ways to solve your problem. what I advise you to do is try to solve it in your own way, then ask here for optimization. check modulo and see how you could do that. or simply subtracting until you get the array condition satisfied. This is the best way to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let num = 118000,
  num_array = [];

while (num > 0) {
  if (num >= 20000) {
    num_array.push(20000);
    num -= 20000;
  } else {
    num_array.push(num);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(num_array);
```

I think this is what you want, please post what you tried, so that it helps to understand where you failed.